# How to print a LinkedHashMap which is inside a List in jsf datatable?

Tags: jsf, el

I am able to print `item.srNor` but I am not able to print `item.details` (where details is a `LinkedHashMap`)

I have got the following datatable in my .xhtml file (jsf)

```
<h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{Handler.List}" var="item">

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="column1" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.srNor}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="column2" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value=""></h:outputText>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="column3" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value=""></h:outputText>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="column4" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value=""></h:outputText>
    </h:column>


    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:outputText value="End" />
    </f:facet>

</h:dataTable>
```

The List in my java class is an Array list.

Any suggestion on this would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you using `item.details` exactly?

Comment: details is a LinkedHashMap which contains key name value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that `#{item.details}` returns a [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). You can just access `Map` values by the associated map key in EL as follows:

```
#{item.details.somekey}
```

This resolves under the covers to `item.getDetails().get("somekey")`.

If the key itself contains reserved EL characters like dots and hyphens, then you can also use the brace notation:

```
#{item.details['some.key']}
```

This resolves to `item.getDetails().get("some.key")`.

Or if the key itself is to be obtained from another variable, then use the unquoted brace notation

```
#{item.details[otherbean.key]}
```

This resolves to `item.getDetails().get(otherbean.getKey())`.

Comment: Many Thanks for the help. All the other map key are running fine. but if the key itself contains a hyphen (-) for e.g key-name, then what notation is used? My Map key is like "key-name" then please suggest at the earliest.

Comment: Use the brace notation as well.

Comment: The size of Handler.List in the above example is 5. But only 4 elements are gettings printed and last element from the List is not getting printed in the datatable. Any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like as a completely different issue. Ask a new question.